# Displaying latecomers of staffs

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display the list of staffs who check into work late in a week. For example the staff checks in at 8.10 when the supposed check in time is at 8.00 AM. I am using datetime for the datetimein and datetimeout field. Can anyone suggest how should I do it?

Comment: I assume you're looking for how to write an SQL statement to select records - Have you attempted to write it yourself yet and ran into a problem? What was that problem? As is, this doesn't really have enough information to answer your question...

Comment: @Chris  haven't tried writing it myself yet, I was just trying by using MIN bcs I thought it would be simple but nothing comes out.

Comment: You can post your code or some input data or something...right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with no sample tables to work from, it's hard to give a clear answer. But I think what you're looking for is the [TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function.

This should get you started in the right direction:

```
SELECT * FROM timeclock_records where TIME(datetimein) > "08:00:00";
```

Comment: my previous code was this
SELECT a.supervisor_id, a.employee_id, e.employee_name, CAST( attendance_datetimein AS TIME ) 
FROM attendance a
JOIN employee e
WHERE e.employee_id = a.employee_id
AND a.attendance_datetimein >  "2014-09-04 08:00:00"

But I changed it according to your answer and it worked.Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Ahhh yes. Next time, make sure to include your attempt that didn't work in the question. It will make it much easier for people to help. Cheers!